# How to setup git server on WIndows XP for Http Access?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, http, git

I dont have a WIndows Server OS. I just have a Windows XP version with me in my system. I  want to setup a Git server in my system for secure Http Access to it from users. How can I do it ?

thanks

Comment: This question is perilously close to a "do my work for me" question because of how general it is and the lack of any indication that you have done much to figure it out yourself before posting.

Comment: i have already installed cygwin, git and all other tools and Im trying. But Im still now successful. Im new to server setup/admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cygwin and install Git, Apache2. Follow the steps given at http://ftp.df.lth.se/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt . ( You need to hack it though. ).

Its do-able IMHO.

Comment: but i wanted this on windows !

Comment: I'm afraid its not possible at the moment.